# Open Weather Map API Current Temperature

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, weather-api

I am using [pyowm](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm) on a Raspberry Pi ZeroW to retrieve the most recently recorded temperature for my location. I want to refresh this periodically to update the reading. At the top of my script I open a connection to OWM using the API key I obtained when I registered for a free account.

My question is whether I can put the statement to retrieve an "observation" location (e.g., weather_at_place, weather_at_zip_code, weather_at_coords) and the "weather" to execute once for the script (i.e., at the top) or whether I need to execute them every time I want to grab the temperature. Basically, do I have to invoke weather_at_...(), get_weather(), and get_temperature() every time OR just get_temperature().

```
owm = pyowm.OWM('OWM_API_KEY')
observation = owm.weather_at_zip_code('POSTAL_CODE', 'COUNTRY_CODE')
weather = observation.get_weather()
while True:
    temp = weather.get_temperature('fahrenheit')["temp"]
    print(temp)
    sleep 300
```

OR

```
owm = pyowm.OWM('OWM_API_KEY')
while True:
    observation = owm.weather_at_zip_code('POSTAL_CODE', 'COUNTRY_CODE')
    weather = observation.get_weather()
    temp = weather.get_temperature('fahrenheit')["temp"]
    print(temp)
    sleep 300
```

I can't determine this from either the [usage examples](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm/blob/master/pyowm/docs/usage-examples.md) nor the [documentation](https://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I'm sure it's probably in the documentation somewhere, but I have not been able to find it. I find information on how often weather stations are polled, forecasts are refreshed, etc. I just have not been able to find information on using the API in a looping scenario for temperature. Just as a matter of understanding. Yes, I could just put everything in the loop, but I also don't want to go over the API calls threshold and get throttled. Basically, I want to make sure I'm a good OWM citizen. Plus, no need to have the execution overhead if it can be avoided.

Thank you!

Comment: A quick look at the [docs for `owm.weather_at_zip_code()`](http://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyowm.webapi25.html#pyowm.webapi25.owm25.OWM25.weather_at_zip_code) says it's _the **currently** observed weather_. To me that says the 2nd code is correct.

Comment: You could be correct. But it could be interpreted as "weather_at_... **always** holds" the current weather and the call to get_temperature then retrieves it w/o having to explicitly call weather_at_... That documentation statement is open to interpretation IMO.

Comment: Look at the [source for `weather_at_zip_code()`](http://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyowm/webapi25/owm25.html?highlight=weather_at_zip_code) and you'll see that's where the API call happens. So code #2 is correct....Just test it. Run each code for a few hours and see which one's data actually changes. If you're worried about the threshold, change the `sleep()` to once every 15 minutes.

Comment: I'd only found the usage documentation and didn't see the documented code itself. As you state, the weather_at_... makes the API call whereas neither get_weather nor get_temperature do. Removes the ambiguity. I still think a documentation wording enhancement would help ;-) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi there, the `weather_at_zip_code` actually calls the OWM API and fetches the current weather observation on a named ZIP code. This gives you back an `Observation` object, that you can manipulate and invoking any method on it **will not** trigger any subsequent API calls. Therefore in your while loop you need to repeat the call to `weather_at_zip_code` in order to always get fresher data

Comment: Thanks. After inspecting the coffee, that's the conclusion I came to. I'm calling weather_at in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Geo location you can use the following endpoint

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139